# Hibernate subclass with foreign key relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, mapping, joined-subclass

I need some help defining the following object hierarchy/ database relationship in Hibernate

From the object sense – Agent is inherited from Person and Agency is inherited from Organization. they are inherited from Party which can have multiple Addresses associated with it

[image]

The database consists of

```
Agent
-ID
-Name
-PartyID (references Party.ID)
```

```
Agency
-ID
-Name
-PartyID (references Party.ID)
```

```
Address
-AddrID
-PartyID (references Party.ID)
-Street
```

```
Party.
-PartyID
```

Comment: Can you sketch your class model with minimal pseudo code? From your description I am not sure how you want the relations.

Comment: class Party { private BigInteger partyID...}
class Organization extends Party { private....}
class Person extends Party {...}
class Agency extends Organization {...}
class Agent extends Person {...}

Comment: I've added a class diagram. If this diagram is inaccurate, feel free to fix it. By the way, do you use annotations or hbm.xml?

Comment: The class diagram is correct. What tool did you use to create it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following could be a start

```
@Entity
public class Party {

  @Id
  private BigInteger partyID;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="party")
  private Set<Address> addresses;

} 

@Entity
public class Organization extends Party {} 

@Entity
public class Person extends Party {} 

@Entity
public class Agency extends Organization {} 

@Entity
public class Agent extends Person {}

@Entity
public class Address{

  @Id
  private BigInteger addressID;

  @ManyToOne
  private Party party;

  private String street;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this article could help you. includes src as well.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hibernate/

community page

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html